# How to deliver a a file with no extension with Nginx?

Tags: html, nginx, configuration

All of my static HTML file have no extension, meaning they are not `index.html`, they are just `index`. How can I tell Nginx to access them and deliver them as HTML files? I have the following configuration.

```
server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /home/davidgatti/Documents/example.com;

        index home

        server_name example.loc;

        location / {
                default_type text/html;

                try_files $uri $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Right now Nginx sends back a `404`.

Comment: What content type is `nginx` sending with the file? If the filename is being interpreted as a different type, you can add `types {}` to your location to remove the types array.

Comment: I updated the questions. It sends back 404 right now.

Comment: What is the full path of the file you are attempting to access when you receive the 404 response, and what is the corresponding entry in the access log? Are there any entries in the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I figure it out:

- `index /home;` needs a slash
- `try_files` needs `$uri.html` not sure why, but without it won't work.

```nginx
#
#   Server Configuration
#
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    #
    #   Use the a default SSL for development.
    #
    include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    #
    #   Tell which folder to server.
    #
    root /home/davidgatti/Documents/Retireryte/YOUR_SITE_NAME/_output;

    #
    #   Set the default file.
    #
    index /home;

    #
    #   Tell Nginx which url is this configuration for.
    #
    server_name login.example.loc;

    #
    #   Default configuration.
    #
    location / {

        #
        #   Since we deliver files with no extension, we need to tell
        #   Nginx what those files are.
        #
        default_type text/html;

        #
        #   First attempt to serve request as file, then
        #   as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;

    }
}
```